# How Thread Safe Is Commons-Configuration2 Synchronizer Across Independent Applications

Tags: java, thread-safety, apache-commons-config

I have a properties configuration file that is accessed by one application and can be modified by another. I need to ensure the reads and writes are synchronized, so that is where I found Apache's Commons-Configuration2 version of PropertiesConfiguration. The documentation states that access to the file can be synchronized similarly as a Read Write lock. However, I couldn't determine the extent of the lock, is it only between threads in the same application or the entire file itself?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to lock and synchronize the config file on your drive.

### Process synchronization

And you are right Commons-Configuration2 sync capabilities. It only supports synchronization between threads within the same process (just like most frameworks with build in synchronization features). The Commons-Configuration2 [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980392/how-thread-safe-is-commons-configuration2-synchronizer-across-independent-applic) have some good examples for thread safety.

### File synchronization

Commons-Configuration2 reads the config file to memory and than realeses it. You can delete or modify it while the program is still running. Commons-Configuration2 will **not** read the file again unless you tell it to do so. If you want to lock the file and prevent modification take a look at [FileLocks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lock-files).

If you want to watch for modification you should have a look at FileWatchers.